# Criação consulta utilizando PIVOT no SQL

Tags: sql

[image: Consulta SQL]

Prezados preciso exibir o resultado dessa consulta em colunas, cada linha representa uma marcação de ponto do funcionário no dia, estou tentando utilizar o pivot, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Quais seriam as colunas da versão pivotada? E a agregação não deveria ser por CHAPA em vez de BATIDA?

Comment: A agregação será por chapa e dia, alterei a consulta dessa imagem, o que está pegando agora são as colunas, pois tenho que fazer 4 colunas (entrada, saída refeição, volta refeição e saída), porém não sei um jeito de pivotear as colunas.

Comment: Alguns SGBDs tem a instrução PIVOT (Oracle, Sql Sever etc) , consulte a respectiva documentação, não tendo a saída pode ser o uso de CASE ou IIF (pesquise por <sql pivot case>

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, criei um row_number para numerar as batidas que são 4, depois usei elas para criar as colunas e usei no pivot, deu certo, obrigado.

```
SELECT  
CHAPA,
NOME,
SECAO,
DATA,
HORARIO_BASE,
HORAS_TRABALHADAS,
[1] ENTRADA,
[2] SAÍDA,
[3] ENTRADA,
[4] SAÍDA,      
ATRASO,
EXTRAEXECUTADO,
ABONO,
ADICIONALNOTURNO    

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ABATFUN.DATA, ABATFUN.CHAPA ORDER BY 
ABATFUN.DATA) LINHA,
        PFUNC.CHAPA,
        PFUNC.NOME,
        PSECAO.DESCRICAO SECAO,
        ABATFUN.DATA,            
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(BATIDA) BATIDA,
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(AAFHTFUN.BASE) HORARIO_BASE,
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(AAFHTFUN.HTRAB) HORAS_TRABALHADAS,
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(AAFHTFUN.ATRASO) ATRASO,
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(AAFHTFUN.EXTRAEXECUTADO) EXTRAEXECUTADO,
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(AAFHTFUN.ADICIONAL) ADICIONALNOTURNO,
        dbo.UNIFAM_CONVMIN(AAFHTFUN.ABONO) ABONO,
        AABONO.DESCRICAO MOTIVO_ABONO,
        CASE WHEN
            (SELECT CODAVISO FROM AAVISOCALCULADO WHERE CODCOLIGADA = 
AAFHTFUN.CODCOLIGADA AND CHAPA = AAFHTFUN.CHAPA AND DATAREFERENCIA = 
AAFHTFUN.DATA AND CODAVISO=1) = 1
            THEN 'MENOS DE 11HRS ENTRE AS JORNADAS' END INTERVALO_JORNADA,
        CASE WHEN
            (SELECT CODAVISO FROM AAVISOCALCULADO WHERE CODCOLIGADA = 
AAFHTFUN.CODCOLIGADA AND CHAPA = AAFHTFUN.CHAPA AND DATAREFERENCIA = 
AAFHTFUN.DATA AND CODAVISO=2) = 2
            THEN 'TRABALHOU MAIS DE 10HRS NO DIA' END 
TOTAL_HORAS_TRABALHADAS

    FROM 
        PFUNC   
            LEFT JOIN ABATFUN ON
            ABATFUN.CODCOLIGADA = PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA
            AND ABATFUN.CHAPA = PFUNC.CHAPA
            LEFT JOIN AAFHTFUN ON
            AAFHTFUN.CODCOLIGADA = PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA
            AND AAFHTFUN.CHAPA = PFUNC.CHAPA
            AND AAFHTFUN.DATA = ABATFUN.DATA
            INNER JOIN PSECAO ON
            PSECAO.CODCOLIGADA = PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA
            AND PSECAO.CODIGO  = PFUNC.CODSECAO
            LEFT JOIN AABONFUN ON
            AABONFUN.CODCOLIGADA = AAFHTFUN.CODCOLIGADA
            AND AABONFUN.CHAPA = AAFHTFUN.CHAPA
            AND AABONFUN.DATA = AAFHTFUN.DATA       
            LEFT JOIN AABONO ON
            AABONO.CODCOLIGADA = AABONFUN.CODCOLIGADA
            AND AABONO.CODIGO = AABONFUN.CODABONO   
    WHERE 
        PFUNC.CODCOLIGADA=1
        AND PFUNC.CODFILIAL=2
        AND PFUNC.CODTIPO<>'A'
        --AND PFUNC.CHAPA='200739' 
        AND ABATFUN.DATA BETWEEN '2018-03-21' AND '2018-04-20'

)TABELACONSULTA

PIVOT

(
    MAX(BATIDA)
    FOR [LINHA] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) 
AS TABELAPIVOT


ORDER BY
DATA
,NOME
```

Comment: Poderia postar a parte que você alterou no código?

Comment: E bom colaborar com a resposta, como o @Don'tPanic pediu, caso contrário essa resposta pode ser apagada por ter pouco conteúdo.

Comment: Coloquei o código no enunciado que consegui fazer e me atendeu no que precisava.